# Default execution policy on java executors

Tags: java, executor

What is the default execution policy on `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`?
Is this documented?

I need to guarantee FIFO.

Comment: Does this matter since all the threads have the same Task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaDoc for [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29) says:

> tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially

If this is not enough for you, have a look at the sources, it uses [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) behind the scenes:

> This queue orders elements FIFO (first-in-first-out).